# Create a table from an array

Tags: php, html

Need help
There are 5 servers

```
$server1 = “1234”;
$server2 = “”;
$server3 = “5463”;
$server4 = “”;
$server5 = “1827”;
```

```
$server = array($server1, $server2, $server3, $server4, $server5);
```

Then curl is initialised

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/$server1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);
$ip = $json[droplet][networks][v4][0][ip_address];
$status = $json[droplet][status];
$currentapp = $json[droplet][image][name];
$hostname = $json[droplet][name];
$memory = $json[droplet][memory];
$cpu = $json[droplet][vcpus]; 
$disk = $json[droplet][disk];
```

And then the result is echoed in a table as this :

```
<tr>                    
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $status; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $currentapp; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $hostname; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $memory; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $cpu; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $disk; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Now please help me here
How do i display data of different servers in different rows.
And if server 2 and 4 are empty then only server 1 3 and 5 should be displayed in 3 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving it is to consider servers as an array . Then user [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to itereate .

```
$serverArray = array();
$serverArray[] = '1234';
$serverArray[] = '';
$serverArray[] = '5463';
$serverArray[] = '';
$serverArray[] = '1827';

foreach( $serverArray as $serverValue )
{
    if( $serverValue <> '' )
    {
        $serverURL = 'https://api.domain.com/' .$serverValue;

        //  cURL code here

        //  Your table display code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First put all the server values in an array. Like this:

```
$server1 = “1234”;
$server2 = “”;
$server3 = “5463”;
$server4 = “”;
$server5 = “1827”;

$serverArray = array(
  $server1,
  $server2,
  $server3,
  $server4,
  $server5,
);


$infoArray = NULL; // To store all the information
$counter = 0;
foreach($serverArray as $server){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/$server1");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  $json = json_decode($result, true);
  $ip = $json[droplet][networks][v4][0][ip_address];
  $status = $json[droplet][status];
  $currentapp = $json[droplet][image][name];
  $hostname = $json[droplet][name];
  $memory = $json[droplet][memory];
  $cpu = $json[droplet][vcpus]; 
  $disk = $json[droplet][disk];

  $infoArray[$counter]['ip'] = $ip;
  $infoArray[$counter]['status'] = $status;
  $infoArray[$counter]['currentapp'] = $currentapp;
  $infoArray[$counter]['hostname'] = $hostname;
  $infoArray[$counter]['memory'] = $memory;
  $infoArray[$counter]['cpu'] = $cpu;
  $infoArray[$counter]['disk'] = $disk;
  $counter++;
}
```

For the view file

```
<?php 
  $output = '';
  foreach($infoArray as $info){
    $output += "<tr>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['ip']}</td>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['status']}</td>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['currentapp']}</td>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['hostname']}</td>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['memory']}</td>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['cpu']}</td>";
    $output += "<td  style='text-align:center'>{$info['disk']}</td>";
    $output += "</tr>";
  }
  echo $output;
```

?>

Comment: results comes out to be "0" even after changing 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/$server1");
to 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/$server");

Answer (score 0):

Finanlly this is working

```
<html>

<?php 

$serverArray = array();
$serverArray[] = '2720973';
$serverArray[] = '277543';
$serverArray[] = '2720153';
$serverArray[] = '';
$serverArray[] = '';  

foreach( $serverArray as $serverValue )
{
    if( $serverValue <> '' )
    {

// initialize curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/$serverValue");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//decodes json and prints id
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$ip = $json[droplet][networks][v4][0][ip_address];
$status = $json[droplet][status];
$currentapp = $json[droplet][image][name];
$hostname = $json[droplet][name];
$memory = $json[droplet][memory];
$cpu = $json[droplet][vcpus]; 
$disk = $json[droplet][disk];
     ?>

<table>
<tr>                   
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $status; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $currentapp; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $hostname; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $memory; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $cpu; ?></td>
<td  style="text-align:center"><?php echo $disk; ?></td>


<?php }
    } ?>
```